# .net GraphServiceClient send email - code sample doesn't work anymore

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I have found this example https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/sending-smtp-email-microsoft-graph-oauth-using-vbnet-elie-karkafy/ and rewrite it into c# like this:

```
static async Task SendEmail()
{
    var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

    var tenantId = ""; // Replace with your Tenant ID
    var clientId = ""; // Replace with Application ID from Overview tab
    var clientSecret = ""; // Replace with the Client Secret

    var options = new TokenCredentialOptions
    {
        AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud
    };

    var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, options);
    var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);

    var message = new Message
    {
        Subject = "This is the subject line",
        Body = new ItemBody
        {
            ContentType = BodyType.Text,
            Content = "This is the body of the email message."
        },
        ToRecipients = new List<Recipient>
        {
            new Recipient
            {
                EmailAddress = new EmailAddress
                {
                    Address = "user@domain.com" // This is the recipient of the message
                }
            }
        }
    };

    await graphClient.Users["myuser@mydomain.com"].SendMail(message, null).Request().PostAsync();
}
```

But it seems that SDK has changed since it errors out with

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1955  Non-invocable member 'UserItemRequestBuilder.SendMail' cannot be used like a method.    MailSend
```

at the line

```
await graphClient.Users["myuser@mydomain.com"].SendMail(message, null).Request().PostAsync();
```

I have found another example in C#: https://medium.com/medialesson/how-to-send-emails-in-net-with-the-microsoft-graph-a97b57430bbd

And it is basically the same code. So it seems that code was correct in previous versions.

I understand the basic of what the error is telling me, but I am not proficient enough in .net and Graph SDK to fix it.
Any help and explanation is much appreciated.

**EDIT**

I have downgraded to graph 4 SDK and the followind code doesn't report any errors, **but it doesn't work**.

```
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.Graph;

namespace MailSend1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            await  SendEmail();
        }


        public static async Task SendEmail()
        {
            var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

            var tenantId = ""; // Replace with your Tenant ID
            var clientId = ""; // Replace with Application ID from Overview tab
            var clientSecret = ""; // Replace with the Client Secret

            var options = new TokenCredentialOptions
            {
                AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud
            };

            var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, options);
            var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);

            var message = new Message
            {
                Subject = "Just a test!",
                Body = new ItemBody
                {
                    ContentType = BodyType.Text,
                    Content = "Does it work?"
                },
                ToRecipients = new List<Recipient>
                {
                    new Recipient
                    {
                        EmailAddress = new EmailAddress
                        {
                            Address = "someuser@gmail.com" // This is the recipient of the message
                        }
                    }
                }
            };

            Console.WriteLine("Mail TO BE sent!");
            bool saveToSentItems = true;

            // Specify the user account to send from. An account in your tenant. It also sends the email.
            await graphClient.Users["test@somedomain.net"].SendMail(message, saveToSentItems).Request().PostAsync();

            Console.WriteLine("Mail sent!");
        }

    }
}
```

The issue is that code runs, but no mail is sent and no error reported.
Also the second writeline statment is never printed.

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example is probably related to SDK v4, but you are using SDK v5 with breaking changes. The code for v5 should be like this

```
static async Task SendEmail()
{
    var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

    var tenantId = ""; // Replace with your Tenant ID
    var clientId = ""; // Replace with Application ID from Overview tab
    var clientSecret = ""; // Replace with the Client Secret

    var options = new TokenCredentialOptions
    {
        AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud
    };

    var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, options);
    var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);

    var body = new SendMailPostRequestBody
    {
        Message = new Message
        {
            Subject = "This is the subject line",
            Body = new ItemBody
            {
                ContentType = BodyType.Text,
                Content = "This is the body of the email message."
            },
            ToRecipients = new List<Recipient>
    {
        new Recipient
        {
            EmailAddress = new EmailAddress
            {
                Address = "user@domain.com" // This is the recipient of the message
            }
        }
    }
        }
    };

    await graphClient.Users["myuser@mydomain.com"].SendMail.PostAsync(body);
}
```

[Upgrade to v5](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/dev/docs/upgrade-to-v5.md)

Comment: This doesn't work, body is not of the correct type.

Comment: I have also created a new project with graph v4, where the sample code seems to work, but it doesn't send email. I added EDIT section in my post.

Comment: @Primoz To your updated code: Try to change `static void Main(string[] args)` to `static async Task Main(string[] args)`

Comment: it works now. 
Care to explain how and why ? I have stopped working with c# at a version 4 and I don't have a clue about async and await. Thank you very much!

Comment: With `void` the `Main` completed before any request has been sent to the Graph API. `async Task` ensures that the request is sent and response is received before `Main` completes (very simple explanation from my side).

Comment: The answer still doesn't work for me either -- using .NET 7 and find that the body is not the correct type

Comment: @ProgrammerBret Could you please create a new question for your problem? It will give a chance also other users to answer. Hard to say from one error message but maybe it can be related to a fact that there is more classes SendMailPostRequestBody in different namespaces. What do you mean by body? Body property of Message or SendMailPostRequestBody?

Answer (score 2):

Since I have to have a '50' reputation to comment on an answer, I will add to the above answer for everyone's question of the body being of the incorrect type: it must be Microsoft.Graph.Users.Item.SendMail type. So, change the code to the following:
`var body = new Microsoft.Graph.Users.Item.SendMail.SendMailPostRequestBody`

That will fix the issue anyone is running into with the code.

Comment: yes thats the issue if one is using Graph package version 5+